# How to get select box name in jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I want to get select box name in jquery.I already know this.name.But I need to get name based on id
I have tried

```
<select name='country' id='select_id'>
<option .........</option>
</select>
```

I need to fetch the name country dynamically using id.I tried the below line

```
$("#select_id").name
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get/set attribute name:

```
$("#select_id").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$("#select_id").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this code
 $("#select_id").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
$("#select_id").prop('name');
```

> jQuery 1.6 introduced the .prop() method for setting or getting
>   properties on nodes and deprecated the use of .attr() to set
>   properties. However, versions up to 1.9 continued to support using
>   .attr() for specific situations. This behavior in the name of
>   backwards compatibility causes confusion when selectors are used that
>   distinguish between attributes and properties.

[**Reference**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

**.attr()** retrieves attributes, while **.prop()** retrieves properties. The two are different things, and always officially have been (though the DOM often has a property to correspond to an attribute). If you have a , where whatever is not an attribute the browser recognizes, you'd use **.attr()** to get the attribute's value.  **.prop()** wouldn't even be able to see it in most browsers.

When you care about the resulting DOM property, use **.prop()**. When you care about the actual HTML attribute, use **.attr()**. It's not really an either/or thing; you can use both in the same code and the universe won't implode even once (assuming you've used them correctly, anyway). :) Just use the one that's suited to the job you're doing at the time, and quit trying to "deprecate" stuff that's not broken.